# OpenCL - atomic_cmpxchg

Tags: opencl, atomic

What does this function do??. I couldn't understand a thing from the OpenCL specification!!
The code below is a snippet from spMV code.

```
atomic_cmpxchg((__global int*)loc, *((int*)&old), *((int*)&sum)) != *((int*)&old)
```

Comment: I just love the sheer emotional energy radiating from this question :)

Answer (score 5):

`atomic_cmpxchg` is "atomic compare and exchange". It implements an atomic version of the standard C99 ternary operation. For the code above it implies the atomic equivalent of the following:

```
p = *loc;
*loc = (p == *old) ? (*sum != *old) : p;
```

with the `atomic_cmpxchg` call returning `p`. The operation is atomic, this means that no other thread can read or write from `loc` until the transaction is completed.